# Orchard NHibernate Model, Updating object

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orchardcms-1.7

Hope this hasnt been asked before but here is my problem. I've create my models like so:

```
public class Survey
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Survey Name is required")]
    [Display(Name="Survey Name")]
    public virtual string SurveyName { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Disabled { get; set; }        
    public virtual IEnumerable<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public virtual int QuestionOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual Enums.QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }
    public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }
    public virtual int Survey_Id { get; set; }

}
```

which in turn has created my migration:

```
// Creating table Survey
        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("Survey", table => table
            .Column("Id", DbType.Int32, column => column.PrimaryKey().Identity())
            .Column("SurveyName", DbType.String)
            .Column("Disabled", DbType.Boolean)
        );

        // Creating table Question
        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("Question", table => table
            .Column("Id", DbType.Int32, column => column.PrimaryKey().Identity())
            .Column("QuestionText", DbType.String)
            .Column("QuestionOrder", DbType.Int32)
            .Column("QuestionType", DbType.String)
            .Column("Survey_Id", DbType.Int32)
        );
```

I've made the assumption that Orchard NHibernate works in the same way as EF in that based on naming conventions my Survey and Survey_Id properties of question map to the same field in the database (my migration would lead me to believe this is correct).

Here's my problem: Using IRepository from Orchard to create an object in the database produces sql that looks like this

```
 INSERT INTO Question (QuestionText, QuestionOrder, QuestionType, Survey_Id, Survey_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

which errors because Survey_Id is there twice.

Any help or advice would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you are not inheriting from ContentPart or ContentPartRecord. 
try this link : [Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations), did help me to understand. 
Along with some of the other tutorials.

Comment: Hi, that's because these are models that I want generated by orchard but won't be usable as a contentpart. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: I had to look at mine again. I think is a NHibernate thing. Change the  '.Column("Survey_Id", DbType.Int32)' to '.Column("Survey_id", DbType.Int32)'.